# Set up of 'sendmail' headers for cron jobs (crontab-user@mydomain.xyz)

Tags: server, cron, sendmail

I use Ubuntu 14 on AWS EC2. 
I have a non-root user `crontab`. Upon cron job completion, an email is to `MAILTO` address, as set in `crontab`. The email sender looks like this: 
 
`root@ip-111-11-0-11.us-east-1.compute.internal`

How can I change the "from" email to either:

- *`crontab-username@my-domain.com`* or
- *`do-not-reply@my-domain.com`* ?

***EDIT-1:***
Following contributed comments, I executed `telnet localhost 25` in terminal and got back:

```
220 ip-111-11-0-11.us-east-1.compute.internal ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1
Tue, 5 Jul 2016 13:38:31 GMT
(No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
```

So my MTA is `sendmail`, and my question becomes:

***How do I configure sendmail so my cron jobs' email headers are as above ?***

Comment: +1 Welcome to AU ! and BTW, yrs is  actually a good question. Let's troubleshoot  a bit ! **1)** determine yr MTA with `$ telnet localhost 25` followed by `quit`.  Post the line that has `220 your-host ESMTP ...` by editing yr question. Notify me in a comment below with `@Cbhihe` in it.

Comment: In parallel, I'd recommend you have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/postfix.html if `postfix is (as per default in Ubuntu) your MTA. Also read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798772/postfix-its-installed-but-how-do-i-test, in particular but not only the last answer. Note that I have no experience with AWS.

Comment: Thank you, @Cbhihe 220 ip-111-11-0-11.us-east-1.compute.internal ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1; Tue, 5 Jul 2016 13:38:31 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]

Comment: I'm guessing that in our case we use sendmail as MTA?

Comment: after spending a bit more time reading on sendmail and doing some tests the problem seems to be unrelated to cron and related to sendmail configuration, which I struggle to understand.

Comment: Just found this on configuring sendmail: 1) In terminal, do: sudo sendmailconfig and type "Y" for each question it asks. -- 2) To edit yr hosts file: sudo vim /etc/hosts and add the following line to the top of the file before saving it. (Comment out any duplicate lines.) -- (newline) 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain my-domain-name-here.xyz. -- In addition for each cron job, keep making sure that yr MAILTO="...." is correctly set as you already mentioned it is.

Comment: I've run into another issue that I didn't had a chance to google yet. adding 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain my-domain-name-here.xyz, breaks sending emails as they stop being sent out. I suspect this is because the email I sent it to is email@my-domain-name-here.xyz; however emails for my-domain-name-here.xyz managed by google. So I suspect adding 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain my-domain-name-here.xyz is causing the server that runs cron job to rout the email locally. but I didn't have time to test this theory.

Comment: Do you use an outgoing smtp server to send out email  ?

Answer (score -1):

`man 5 crontab` will solve your problem. It says, in part:

```
An  active line in a crontab will be either an environment setting or a
   cron command.  An environment setting is of the form,

       name = value

   where the spaces around  the  equal-sign  (=)  are  optional,  and  any
   subsequent  non-leading  spaces  in  value  will  be  part of the value
   assigned to name.  The value string may be placed in quotes (single  or
   double, but matching) to preserve leading or trailing blanks.

   Several   environment   variables  are  set  up  automatically  by  the
   bcron-exec(8) program.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME, USER, and
   HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's owner.

   In  addition to LOGNAME, USER, HOME, and SHELL, bcron-exec(8) will look
   at MAILTO if it has any reason to send mail  as  a  result  of  running
   commands  in  ``this''  crontab.  If MAILTO is defined (and non-empty),
   mail is sent to the user so named.  If  MAILTO  is  defined  but  empty
   (MAILTO=""), no mail will be sent.  Otherwise mail is sent to the owner
   of the crontab.  This option is  useful  if  you  decide  on  /bin/mail
   instead  of  /usr/lib/sendmail  as your mailer when you install cron --
   /bin/mail doesn't do aliasing, and UUCP usually doesn't read its mail.
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves my problem. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: What part of `man 5 crontab` do you not understand? It seems you didn't read it and just posted a "solve it for me" whine.

Comment: -1 You answer does not solve any of OP's issues. Everybody agrees that suggesting reading a pertinent man page section to him is good practice. But not answering the question and then abusing OP's author is not GP, IMHO.

Comment: @Cbhihe: My answer does explain why email is from `root@ip-111-11-0-11.us-east-1.compute.internal` ("`bcron-exec(8) will look
   at MAILTO if it has any reason to send mail  ...`") and explains that if OP puts `MAILTO=OP@example.org` in his crontab, the email will come from the crontab's user. Did you read the whole `man` page?